# List<T>.GetRange throws argument exception

Tags: c#, arrays, list, mergesort

I'm working on a merge sort algorithm in c# using List and I get a weird error.

```
class SortingAlgorithms
{
    public static List<int> mergeSort(List<int> array)
    {
        if (array.Count == 1)
            return array;

        List<int> a1 = array.GetRange(0, (int)array.Count / 2);
        int x = array.Count - 1;
        int y = array.Count/2 + 1;
        List<int> a2 = array.GetRange(y, x);
        ...
```

This code throws the following exception: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

This might seem rather straightforward. But it isn't. You see, when debugging these were the values:

array.Count = 8

a1.Count = 4

x = 7

y = 5

a2 = Null

My question: Why can't I get the range of 5 - 7 in an array that has 8 elements in it?

Comment: Because you are trying to get the range of Y to X (7 to 5) instead of X to Y?

Comment: No. I'm tying to get the range Y(5) to X(7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the signature of GetRange is not `GetRange(lower, upper)`, it's [`GetRange(index, count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that the error message talks about *offset* and *length*.

In other words: it does not return the range `[y, x]`, it returns `x` elements starting at `y`.

To get the elements from `y` to `x` (including y and x), use `GetRange(y, y - x + 1)` instead. In your case, that would be `array.GetRange(y, array.Count - y)`.

PS: Since your `array` is not actually an array, I suggest you use a different variable name.

Comment: Okay. I now understand that it does not return a sublist but the entire list starting at index till the count. Thanks for explaining. But i don't really understand how GetRange(y, array.Count - y) / GetRange(5, 3) makes sense.

Comment: @Stephen: `GetRange(5, 3)` means: Give me 3 elements, starting at element 5, i.e. `[element5, element6, element7]`. It's analogous to methods such as [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).